# Match two data frames by common lat, long pair and create a new column out of it

Tags: r

I have two dataframes with coordinates:

```
lat<-c(36.09163,36.16152,36.13027
,36.24514)
lon<-c(-95.84311,-95.83745
,-96.10115,-95.84191)
weight<-c(87,45,656,78)
df1<-data.frame(lat,lon,weight)



lat<-c(36.09163,36.16152,36.130279,36.24514)
lon<-c(-95.84311,-95.83745
       ,-96.101159,-95.841919)
df2<-data.frame(lat,lon)
```

What I want to achieve is find all the common lat long pairs when both of them have at least 5 common decimal digits (and of course integer) with a lat-long pair of the other dataframe. When this happens then the second dataframe should take the relative `weight` value of the 1st dataftame in a new column named `weight`. In the toy example I give all the pairs should be considered the same. If not then the new weight value shoul be 0. I need something like:

```
n<-merge(df1,df2,all.x=TRUE)
```

but I do not know how to handle the digit issue since some coordinates have 5 and other have 6 digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sqldf` package might be helpful here, since your problem can be neatly formulated using a SQL join between the two data frames:

```
library(sqldf)

sql <- "SELECT df2.lat, df2.lon, COALESCE(df1.weight, 0) weight
        FROM df2
        LEFT JOIN df1
            ON ROUND(df1.lat - 0.5, 5) = ROUND(df2.lat - 0.5, 5) AND
               ROUND(df1.lon - 0.5, 5) = ROUND(df2.lon - 0.5, 5)"

df2 <- sqldf(sql)
```

Note that it appears that you want to *truncate* each lat/lng value and then compare it.  That is, the following two latitude values from the two data frames should be considered equivalent:

```
36.130279
36.13027
```

We can do this by truncating to 5 digits and then comparing.  Since SQLite does not have a floor function, we may simulate by subtracting `0.5` and then rounding to 5 digits.

Also, if a given lat/lng pair could match to more than one pair in the other data frame then your current question is not well defined, and you would need to provide other logic to handle this.

Comment: tnx for your answer. It works with weight instead of t1.weight. You are right about this but I cannot think of a diferent logic in order to find an acceptable way to extract the real common pairs.

Comment: The problem you are having is a somewhat common one here on the site.  The issue is that the numeric type you are using to store the lat/lng values are not exact (I think).  If you store everything with exact precision, then you won't have to use rounding tricks.

Comment: I think that you are right. The more the digits the better the precision but this is how the data was given to me.

Comment: The RSQLite R package provides a loadable extension that includes additional functions such as `floor` and `sqldf` loads it automatically so you actually can use `floor`.  Run this command from within R to get a list of the additional functions available:  `help("initExtension", "RSQLite")`  Also even without that you can cast to integer `select cast(4.8 as integer)`